# Changing content of categories pages

Tags: php, mysql, menuitem, categories

I have a table called categoria with 10 rows:

```
(idcateg, descri) VALUES 
(1, 'Action'), 
(2, 'Classic'), 
(3, 'Fight'), 
(4, 'Others'), 
(5, 'Puzzles'), 
(6, 'Racing'), 
(7, 'Shooting'), 
(8, 'Sports'), 
(9, 'Tower Defense'), 
(10, 'Zombie');
```

and it's all linked to a page called link_categoria.php

```
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=1">Action</a>
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=2">Classic</a>
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=3">Fight</a>
<a href="link_categoria.php?cat=4">Others</a>
...
```

What I want to know is, like this site: http://www.gameonline.org 
I want to change the information of each page as I click on the categories. How do I do that?

Thanks

```
mysql_select_db($database_gameconnection, $gameconnection);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY categoria.descri";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))
{
echo '<a href="link_categoria.php?cat='.
   $row_Recordset1['idcateg'] .'">'.
   $row_Recordset1['descri']. '</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `link_categoria.php` you can get the category using `$_GET['cat']`

```
// Check if $_GET['cat'] is set [ie. ?cat=##] and is numeric
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])){

  // Get categoria and escape it before using in the query
  $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);

  // Query to get categoria title
  $sql_categoria = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE idcateg = $cat";
  $query_categoria = mysql_query($sql_categoria, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error()); 
  $categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_categoria);

  // Echo the categoria title
  echo '<h1>'.$categoria['descri']. '</h1>';

} // ends if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat']))
```

Assuming you have a table of games that are listed by categoria

```
gameid | idcateg | game
  1         3      game1
  2         5      game2
....
```

you can do a similar query to get a list of the games in that categoria

```
// Check if $_GET['cat'] is set [ie. ?cat=##] and is numeric
if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])){

  // Get categoria and escape it before using in the query
  $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);

  $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE idcateg = $cat";
  $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error());
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

  while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))
  {
  echo '<a href="game.php?gameid='.
     $row_Recordset1['gameid'] .'">'.
     $row_Recordset1['game']. '</a><br>';
  }
}
```

---

Note, from the docs - the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Comment: That's excellent but why am I getting this error? Notice: Undefined index: cat in C:\xampp\htdocs\link_categoria.php on line 186
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1<?php 
$cat=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']); - Line 186

Comment: `Undefined index: cat` will happen when you are on `link_categoria.php`, as it is looking for `link_categoria.php?cat=#`. This can be resolved by adding a check to see if `$_GET['cat']` is set & numeric `if(isset($_GET['cat']) && is_numeric($_GET['cat'])){...}`. I have added it to my answer.